# Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in include()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

In order to theme a specific page in my site, I created a file called node--2.tpl.php. Per some other tutorials I read, I added this to my template.php file:

```
function mtheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if (request_path() == 'node/2') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__2';
  }
}
```

On this page, I wanted the region called schools_landing to be rendered. As such, node--2.tpl.php looks like this and nothing else:

```
<?php print render($page['schools_landing']); ?>
```

After doing so, I began seeing the following error messages in the top of the administrator overlay:

```
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in include() (line 1 of /home/something/public_html/project/sites/all/themes/mtheme/node--2.tpl.php).
```

Additionally, I can write text in the node--2.tpl.php file and it displays fine (instead of the default page content), but I can't get blocks to render inside of the region at all. If I assign a block to the schools_landing block, I see nothing on the page.

1. Is this the right process to define custom content on a specific page?
2. How can I fix the error causing the scalar value as an array error message?
3. How can I get my blocks to begin rendering in the region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [node template](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7), `$page` is a boolean value, not an array. That is the reason you get that error.
[template_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) sets it with the following code.

```
$variables['page']      = $variables['view_mode'] == 'full' && node_is_page($node);
```

It is `hook_preprocess_page()` that gets the variable `$page` with the value you are expecting.
[template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) contains the following code.

```
  foreach (system_region_list($GLOBALS['theme']) as $region_key => $region_name) {
    if (!isset($variables['page'][$region_key])) {
      $variables['page'][$region_key] = array();
    }
  }
```

[page.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7) describes `$page` as:

> Regions:
>
> - `$page['help']`: Dynamic help text, mostly for admin pages.
> - `$page['highlighted']`: Items for the highlighted content region.
> - `$page['content']`: The main content of the current page.
> - `$page['sidebar_first']`: Items for the first sidebar.
> - `$page['sidebar_second']`: Items for the second sidebar.
> - `$page['header']`: Items for the header region.
> - `$page['footer']`: Items for the footer region.

Extra regions can be implemented from themes.

As side note, `template_preprocess_node()` already suggests the following template names.

```
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $node->type;
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $node->nid;
```

There is no need to suggest them for your theme, or in a custom module.

Comment: Okay, your side note made plenty of sense. I removed my suggestion as its not necessary. For the rest, should I be using Page templates instead of node templates? That is, if I want to render the schools_landing region on a specific page, should I create a page template that does so?